# Easiest way to upload a collection of files to a server

Tags: upload, webclient

Could anyone guide me as to the best way to upload a collection of files from a directory to a server from within a WPF client.
We have ftp access, and as such I have been looking at WebClient.UploadFile.

There seems to be a number of methods available through webclient though, and Im not sure which would be the most suitable.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: And how is WPF related to it? I can't really see any connection..

Comment: right, it's an WPF application.

Comment: There's really no WPF component to the file uploading itself - webclient works fine for that...

Comment: updated title to reflect this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144230.aspx) or [WebClient.UploadFileAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144233.aspx) to upload the files, with one call per file.

This can be as simple as:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();

foreach(var filePath in files)
    wc.UploadFile("ftp://myserver.com/path", filePath);
```

Comment: Thanks - by the way, it appears that there is no way to authenticate on the ftp server prior to upload. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Just set the WebClient.Credentials property prior to calling UploadFile: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.credentials.aspx